# Binding does not work in ViewModel command method MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a `MVVM WPF` application where i bind several values from `ViewModel` to View.

Now i have created a new `ViewModel` where i have to bind a value to a `TextBox` after a `Button` click. When i tried this simple binding it didn't work for me. To my surprise the binding works when the value is assigned in the constructor.

I'm confused.

ViewModel:

```
public ABCViewModel{
       txtItems = "Hello world";      //this works
}


 private string m_stxtItem = "";

        public string txtItems
        {
            get { return this.m_stxtItem; }

            set
            {
                if (this.m_stxtItem != value)
                {                    
                    this.m_stxtItem = value;

                }
            }
        }

public ICommand BindTextValue { get { return new RelayCommand(SeriesBinding); } }

 private void SeriesBinding()
        {
               txtItems = "Hi";                         //does not work

        }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding txtItems,Source={StaticResource ABCViewModel}}" />

<Button Command="{Binding BindTextValue,Source={StaticResource ABCViewModel}}">Click</Button>
```

Why this didn't work and where am i wrong?

Comment: it doesn't work because you didn't implement property change notification in txtItems property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply answer: you are missing the INotifyPropertyChanged-implementation required for automatic data binding.

Extended answer to why it works when setting the value in the constructor:
the initial binding (reading of the value) from the view happens AFTER your ViewModel-constructor was called and your value was set

Comment: property change notifications are not necessary done via INotifyPropertyChanged. it is not required. it is just most common

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your ViewModel.

Here's some MSDN links on what the interface is and how to implement it:

[INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface)

Basically because you've set the ViewModel as the DataSource for the View, upon construction, the View will look to the ViewModel for its values. From this point onwards the ViewModel needs some mechanism for notifying the View of changes. The View is not periodically updated or anything like that. This is where the INotifyPropertyChanged interface steps in. The WPF framework looks out for these events being fired and makes the View refresh its value.